# How can I use terraform to do this project using VsCode "Building a CI/CD Pipeline with AWS,K8S,Docker,Ansible,Git,Github,ApacheMaven,Jenkins"

Tags: hcl

I need to create my HCL file on VsCode and then run it. I don't know how to do it

I tried HCL CLI it didn't work out. I am looking at runing the whole job using a single code if possible, I mean a single HCL code, so that I can simple add Terraform apply for the job to be a go

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.